# Scanning for Bluetooth Devices using Plugin.BluetoothLE but name is blank

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, .net-maui

I'm using the NuGet package `Plugin.BluetoothLE` v6.3.0.19 and I can scan for nearby devices but mostly the names are blank.  A few devices show their names but most do not.  I also cannot see the mac address of the device I'm looking for.

The scenario is that I know the device name but need to look up the mac for connecting.

As I check the devices I need to check the device.name to see if it matches the device I'm looking for.  If found it will attempt to pair and connect.

I'm thinking this LE (Low Energy) version does not get the names from every device unless it broadcasts it.  So maybe I need to request more info?  If so I don't know how to do that with this plugin.

```
var adapter = CrossBleAdapter.Current;
adapter.ScanExtra(new ScanConfig { ScanType = BleScanType.Balanced });
var scanner = CrossBleAdapter.Current.Scan().Subscribe(scanResult =>
{
    var x = scanResult.Device;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"{x.Name} - {x.Status} _ {x.ToString()}");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the BluetoothLE, but I found a [course](https://didourebai.medium.com/integrate-and-use-the-ble-plugin-for-xamarin-edd6d8a1096d) about the problem. I hope this can help you.

In addition, you can put the issue on this [git](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le). People who know the problem may help you.